# Database-first key annotations unrecognized by entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am trying to use partial classes to decorate EF's auto-generated entity models for SQL views that I have access to. These views are 1:1 representations of tables, but omit the primary keys and foreign key constraints present in the database. I would like to reproduce these keys/constraints with data annotations, but attempting to use them within EF fails.

Any attempts to use Include or Find within LINQ always fail. The foreign key defined here, for example, does not seem to be recognized:

```
public class FactTimeEntryMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeEntryKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DimEmployee.EmployeeKey")]
    public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof(FactTimeEntryMetadata))]
public partial class FactTimeEntry { }

public class DimEmployeeMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof(DimEmployeeMetadata))]
public partial class DimEmployee { }
```

In this example, the FactTimeEntry contains TimeEntryKey as a primary, and a column for EmployeeKey, referring to the foreign key in DimEmployee. Is my syntax off in some way, or is this simply not possible with Entity Framework database-first?

**Edit:**

I have also tried to add a virtual reference to the object, like so:

```
public class FactTimeEntryMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeEntryKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DimEmployee")]
    public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }

    public virtual DimEmployee DimEmployee { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof(FactTimeEntryMetadata))]
public partial class FactTimeEntry { }

public class DimEmployeeMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof(DimEmployeeMetadata))]
public partial class DimEmployee { }
```

but was also unsuccessful this way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use the `MetadataTypeAttribute` to assign the `KeyAttribute` for Entity Framework.  If they are partial classes, just duplicate the Keyed property with the `KeyAttribute`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm not sure what you mean. The partial classes are intended to be empty -- if I try to set the `KeyAttribute` of `EmployeeKey` in the partial `FactTimeEntry` class, for example, it will have been defined in two places, both there and in the auto-generated code by EF.

Comment: Furthermore, I was hoping you _could_ set `KeyAttribute` with `MetadataTypeAttribute`... they both belong to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, so they should in theory work just as other annotations, such as `DataMember` and `Serializable`, do (and I know those two function in the way above).

Comment: You can't use this dot notation. The property you refer to by `[ForeignKey]` must be in the type itself. But why don't you add the keys/associations in the edmx designer?

Comment: This was more for personal interest than anything else; I read that setting keys was possible with annotations in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only three options using [ef-database-first](/questions/tagged/ef-database-first):

1. Put your keys and relationships in your database.  Relational Databases were created to be relational.  If you don't do that, why use a database?
2. As Gert Arnold metion in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021686/database-first-key-annotations-unrecognized-by-entity-framework#comment-40762485), edit the EDMX and assign your associations.
3. Edit the T4 templates with custom code to add Keys/relationships to your objects.